# linux - Purpose of the LISTER shell variable

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to find what exactly a `LISTER` shell variable is used for. I'm doubting that it is for listing all the environmental variables but couldn't able to use it and also couldn't find it using `man LISTER`.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Answer (score 2):

The `LISTER` environment variable is used by the `mailx` command to list folders. The default value is simply `ls`.

[Documentation from the Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html)

> LISTER
>
> Determine a string representing the command for writing the contents of the folder directory to standard output when the folders command is given (see folders in Commands in mailx). Any string acceptable as a command_string operand to the sh -c command shall be valid. If this variable is null or not set, the output command shall be ls. The effects of this variable are unspecified if the User Portability Utilities option is not supported.

Comment: Thanks! But how do we use it?

Comment: @SrujanSimha It's not really useful on modern systems, since the mailx command is used for the particular model of how email on unix systems was done in the 1980s and not typically used today. If you don't use mailx you can just ignore it. Where exactly did you find this to want to ask the question in the first place?